# call function in postgresql

Tags: function, postgresql, call

I made a simple function as part of my homework but for the life of me I can't figure out how to call it and test it. Can anyone tell me how?

```
    -- Procedure
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addDoctor (
    a INT,
    b VARCHAR (20),
    c VARCHAR (20)
) RETURNS VOID
LANGUAGE plpsql
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO doctor
    VALUES (a,b,c);
END;
$BODY$
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [SELECT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html):

```
SELECT function_name();
```

Comment: I tried that and it is giving me the error syntax error at or near "SELECT". Maybe I am butchering the function, but it is not throwing an error. I'll edit to show my code.

Comment: LANGUAGE plpsql is wrong, this should be plpgsql with an extra "g".

Comment: Query failed: ERROR:  query has no destination for result data\nHINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION analyzer(character varying, character varying)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
--
begin
--
    execute 'analyze '||quote_ident($1)||'.'||quote_ident($2) ;
return 1 ;
--
end ;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. How does exactly this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to call function just to check for exceptions that can occur there go perform:

```
PERFORM f_foo(i);
```

if you need a result, go select

```
SELECT function_name();
```